# Getting lowest student mark, how would I go about building this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I would like to get some help with this as I have been trying to learn sub queries but I'm still struggling with more "complex" bits.

Here is the sample, with three tables.

```
dbo.Teacher
StaffID | FirstName | LastName

dbo.Modules
StaffID | ModuleID | ModuleDesc

dbo.StudentModule
ModuleID | OverallMark
```

There is more rows obviously but this is everything that is relevant to my question.

Now, I need to show the lowest mark given by EACH teacher on ANY module.
So basically the lowest OverallMark given by a teacher (in general) to any student, on any module.

AND then I need to display all the information so

```
StaffID | FirstName | LastName | ModuleID | ModuleDesc | OverallMark
```

The relation is kind of obvious (StaffID - StaffID | ModuleID - ModuleID)

```
SELECT m.ModuleID , 
 m.ModuleDescription , 
 t.FirstName , 
 t.Surname , 
 t.StaffID , 
 (
   SELECT MIN(sm.OverallMark) 
   FROM dbo.StudentModule sm 
   WHERE m.ModuleID = sm.ModuleID AND m.StaffID = t.StaffID
 ) AS OverallMark 
 FROM dbo.Modules m 
 JOIN dbo.Teacher t ON m.StaffID = t.StaffID 
 ORDER BY 
 (
   SELECT MIN(sm.OverallMark) FROM dbo.StudentModule sm WHERE m.ModuleID = 
   sm.ModuleID AND m.StaffID = t.StaffID
 ) ASC
```

Comment: Did you try writing any query? Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: I don't really know what to post. Since today morning I wrote like 10 different queries but I always get stuck on the last bit, depending on my starting point. So I don't really know what to post as I have few queries that only get part of the job done.

Comment: Where's your query???  If you have 10 different queries, why don't you post one of them?

Comment: @Siwyj, Did you try using joins and min/max functions?

Comment: Can you add some sample data and what you expect the result would be? I'm still not 100% clear on "the lowest mark given by EACH teacher on ANY module".

Comment: @AdamV
Ok so.
I have 2 teachers in total James and Karen and I want to see the lowest mark James gave to any student on any module and I want to see Karen's lowest mark given to any student on any module. So my result set should only have 2 rows ONE for James ONE for Karen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT StaffID, FirstName, LastName, ModuleID, ModuleDesc, OverallMark
FROM (
    SELECT t.StaffID, t.FirstName, t.LastName, m.ModuleID, m.ModuleDesc, sm.OverallMark
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY m.StaffID ORDER BY sm.OverallMark) AS TheRank
    FROM Teacher t
    JOIN Modules m ON m.StaffID = t.StaffID
    JOIN StudentModule sm ON sm.ModuleID = m.ModuleID
) a
WHERE TheRank = 1
```

Comment: This works as intended but I don't understand why it works, would you mind explaining what is happening here?

Comment: @SiwyJ In the inner query, I add a column that display row number partition by `StaffID`, ordering the `OverallMark` from lowest to highest.  Then the outer query, I just grab the rows that has row number column = 1 (ie lowest `OverallMark` for each teacher because that's how I was ordering it).  Try to run the inner query.  Maybe you will have a clearer picture.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    t.FirstName
    , t.LastName
    , MIN( sm.OverallMark ) AS LowestMark
FROM dbo.Teacher t
INNER JOIN dbo.Module m
    ON t.StaffID = m.StaffID
INNER JOIN dbo.StudentModule sm
    ON m.ModuleID = sm.ModuleID
GROUP BY
    t.FirstName, t.LastName
ORDER BY
    t.FirstName, t.LastName;
```

Comment: Nope, that returns me all the lowest marks for all the modules, I want only the lowest mark for each teacher not for each module.